# C++ thread can't abort after being joined

Tags: c++, multithreading, visual-studio, terminate

So I have 2 threads running in my program and I eventually want them to terminate when this function is called:

```
void AutoClicker::TerminateThreads()
{
    programrunning = false;
    clicker.join();
    hotkeyLoop.join();
    terminateThread = true;
}
```

And after that is called the threads are supposed to run this code:

```
while (1)
{
    while (programrunning)
    {
        mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, 0, 0, 0, 0);
        mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, 0, 0, 0, 0);
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(delay));
    }

    if (terminateThread) {
        std::terminate();
    }
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(200));
}
```

But the last `if` statement doesn't seem to be called. It is located inside the threads I am trying to terminate, so it should just work right? I am pretty new to threads so I don't really know how to do this, but this is what I found online:

> "When a `std::thread` object gets destroyed it is not allowed to be joinable(), i.e., one of two things have to happen before it is destroyed:

> It was detached and the thread has gone into the wild and there is pretty much no control over whether it has finished or not.

> The thread has been `join()`ed."

Comment: If this is the real code, you have no guarantee the thread will ever see the change to `programrunning` since there's no synchronization of any kind. Worse, one thread might access `programrunning` while another thread is modifying it, which is likely prohibited by whatever threading standard you are coding to. (The C++ standard prohibits it, unless `programrunning` is a `std::atomic` or something, which we can't tell.)

Comment: I'm sorry I am very new to threads, but how would I sync up programrunning, since I am also changing it in another function where it looks if the hotkey is pressed and if so toggles the programrunning variable and that works fine

Comment: Assuming you are using C++ standard threads, you have to follow their rules. The C++ standard (in section 1.10) says that a program with a data race exhibits undefined behavior. Your program has a data race because one thread can modify `programrunning` at precisely the same time another thread is accessing it. You are simply not allowed to do that. "This International Standard imposes no requirements on the behavior of programs that contain undefined behavior. ... Any such data race results in undefined behavior." You cannot allow threads to trample on each other and must coordinate them.

Comment: (Ignore the above if `programrunning` is a `std::atomic` as that does not allow two operations to occur concurrently due to its internal synchronization and so would not be a data race.)

Comment: It's not clear from the code, but if that `while` loop is running as part of one of the threads that are being joined in the first code snippet, the code in the `while` loop won't see that change to `terminateThread`. The calls to `join()` both block until the corresponding thread ends, so the assignment comes too late.

Comment: @PeteBecker That's the desired behavior. The call to `std::terminate` handles the error case where somehow the thread is still running even after it was commanded to stop and waited for. The missing thing is the loop termination condition that allows the thread to normally finish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things to start off with:

- Do not call `std::terminate()`. It is not a nice way to tear down your program, and may leave open files and other OS resources hanging. Also, it applies to your entire program, not just the thread you call it in.
- If you want a `std::thread` to terminate, then just return from it or allow it to reach the end of the thread function.

With that out of the way, here is a small program showing how I would do something like what you describe:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <atomic>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>

void threadfunc(std::atomic<bool>& running)
{
    while (running) {
        std::cout << "beep\n";
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
    }
}

void waitThread(std::atomic<bool>& running)
{
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(10));
    running = false;
}

int main()
{
    std::atomic<bool> running = true;

    std::thread t1(threadfunc, std::ref(running));
    std::thread t2(waitThread, std::ref(running));
    t1.join();
    t2.join();
}
```

Hopefully you can scavenge some bits here to make your program work.

EDIT:
Clarifying some stuff from a comment OP made to another answer:

Something like: `std::thread t1(threadfunc, std::ref(running));` creates an active thread that executes the provided function. Once that function stops (returns) the thread is left in a zombie state, where it is not executing but still active and holding resources.

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/joinable

> A thread that has finished executing code, but has not yet been joined
> is still considered an active thread of execution and is therefore
> joinable.

In order to pull the thread out of this zombie state and clean up its resources, you have to call `join()` on it. Note that you can call `join()` on that thread before OR after it finishes execution - if you join before, you block until the joined thread is done, if you join after, the lingering thread is cleaned up and you immediately continue.

Alternatively, you can call `detach()` on the thread:

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/detach

> Separates the thread of execution from the thread object, allowing
> execution to continue independently. Any allocated resources will be
> freed once the thread exits.

But once you have detached a thread you can no longer join it, and having your main thread exit while there is still live-but-detached threads running kills the detached threads in a not-nice way. So only do that if you are sure the detached thread will finish before the main thread.

Comment: I would use a cv/mutex/bool and wait for on them to permit responsive shutdown, rather than waiting a sleep cycle

Answer (score 1):

You don't really have all the code here, but I'm guessing the method in the clicker thread probably looks something like

```
void clickerThreadFunction()
{
  while(programrunning)
  {
    // do stuff
  }

  if (terminateThread)
  {
    std::terminate();
  }
}
```

If this is the case, then looking at the code

```
programrunning = false;
clicker.join();
```

the first line will cause the `while` loop in the clicker thread to exit.  The rest of the `clicker` method will run, including the `if (terminateThread)` check, which will fail because you haven't set `terminateThread` to true.  Only then, once we've hit the bottom of `clickerThreadFunction`, will `clicker.join()` return, because `std::thread::join` waits for a thread to finish and then returns control.

Anyway I'm not clear what you're trying to do here.  The purpose of `std::terminate` is to immediately crash the program.  If you want that to happen it's not clear why you're bothering with joining the threads since you wouldn't reach that part anyway.

Comment: Sorry for not adding enough information I  have updated my post to show the whole thread

Comment: Okay, so seeing the given code the problem is what I described above: there is no way for the loops to terminate, so the call to `clicker.join()` will never return.

Comment: (I guess "the problem" is stretching it, because the rest of the code doesn't make sense either.)

Answer (score 1):

Do you know what `join` does? `join` waits for the thread to finish.

Your `TerminateThreads` function sets programrunning to false, then waits for the threads to finish, then sets terminateThread to true.

The thread keeps running until terminateThread becomes true, so when the TerminateThreads function is called, it never gets to to the part where it sets terminateThread to true, because it's waiting for the threads to finish.

Comment: Ohh I see, but then how ould I terminate the thread since another post said that the thread should be joined before being terminated?

Comment: @daniëldegroot that is talking about terminating (destroying) the thread object in the main thread. Not terminating the actual thread. You can terminate the thread, then the main thread join it, then the main thread can destroy the thread object. Or, the main thread can detach the thread object, and then the thread object can be destroyed while the thread is still running.

Comment: @daniëldegroot, just to be really clear; A `std::thread` is not a thread.  A thread is an object in the operating system that executes your program's code. A `std::thread` is an object in your program that acts as a "handle" on the operating system object. And, the lives of the `std::thread` object and the operating system object are not strictly linked. Either one potentially can end before the other. When the life of a thread ends, we say it was "terminated." When the life of an object in your program ends, we say it was "destroyed."

Comment: @SolomonSlow • Good point, since that's a subtle but important distinction.  If the `std::thread` object is destroyed, the **thread** can still be running, but now there is no *handle* to it, which means it can no longer be joined or detached (if not already done so), and the thread will be in that "zombie" state when it finishes executing (if not already detached).

Comment: @Eljay actually you must join or detach before destroying the std::thread object, or else your program crashes.

Comment: @user253751 • I stand corrected!  Crashing helps as a safety feature.  Is that a UB situation, or is crashing (I presume `std::terminate`) mandated?

Comment: @Eljay it's mandated, check the documentation